# AWS Code Build errors out with "incorrect commid ID" when we use branch instead of commit ID in the cli

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

Code Build throws out "incorrect commit ID" on the AWS Console, when we use branch instead of commit ID in the cli.

Passing branch name to the "aws codebuild" command is supported, and doesn't throw any error during executing.  But when I look at the Code Build console, I see the "incorrect commit ID" message.

Here is what I am running

```
aws codebuild create-project \
        --name "myclient-${shortName}" \
        --source ${source} \
        --source-version ${shortName} \
        --artifacts ${artifacts} \
        --environment ${environment} ......
```

Comment: We can't reproduce this issue. Can you provide more details (step-by-step on how to repro)? Which source provider were you using? What was the branch name you used? Is this still reproducible for you on AWS CodeBuild console UI?